# Android: Pass an Object into a CustomDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I've found plenty of simple AlertDialog examples out there, but the tutorials and information I've come across doesn't seem to come close enough to what I need to do to help me solve my problem. I'm stumped.

I'm working on a mapping app, and after the user's search results come back I've got a list of the 3 closest results for their query. The results are stored in an array of "Targets" objects, and now I want to pass this array of objects to a dialog box that will let the user click the destination they want to navigate to. Each Targets object has (as instance variables) an index, a latitude, a longitude, a name, an address, and a distance from the current location. At this point, all I really want in the clickable list are distance to the location (rounded to hundredths of a mile):

```
Math.round(target[i].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0 + " Miles to Destination"
```

(maybe that has to be made into one String, I don't know.)

and the name of the destination:

```
target[i].getName()
```

Ideally, I'd like these two fields to be printed in nicely aligned columns. I think I need to do this by setting widths in my list layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

OK, that's as far as I've gotten. How do I construct a dialog that will accept my Targets[] and display choices for a user? (Sorry I don't have any code to show you as a starting point for my dialog. Nothing I've tried works at all so it didn't seem worth it to paste it here.)

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a `Parcelable` target object?

Comment: I never could get this to work the way I wanted. The programming was a bit above my head. That's OK, though, I took the app in a different direction and the results are acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

There is such thing like [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Try to use it. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, well, I had gotten that far on my own.

Comment: How do I construct a dialog that will accept my Targets[] Extend Dialog and make your own constructor with any parameter.